# Can Wireshark capture traffic from host to VM?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm troubleshooting a TFTP server in a virtualbox environment which is not reachable from outside, so I dediced to run Wireshark on my Windows host computer.
What I currently don't understand is if I'm expected to see any traffic going from my host to the VM (which is running in bridge mode).

If I issue a ping to a "real" device in the network I see the following

```
28236   1264.233955 192.168.2.147   192.168.2.142   ICMP    74  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=5439/16149, ttl=128 (reply in 28237)
```

The device responds... but if I ping my VM, which also responds, I get no such entry. Is traffic with destination VM not sent out to the network as any other traffic?

Comment: Generally it can. You need to point it to the interface which in the host represents the connection to the VM. However, Virtualbox makes modifications to the networking stack and its bridge is not strictly "a bridge" but a very strange creature. YMMV. Anyway this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with "reasonable business IT practices", because no people in a sane mind run production servers in Virtualbox.

Comment: Well, the tftp server serves development purpose only.
Why do I need to point it to the VM interface? Is the host using a different interface for different pings? I don't want to see all the trafic going into the VM, I'm, for now, wondering why I don't see the ping leaving my host interface.

Comment: Not a "VM interface", but to an interface in the host that represents the connection between host and VM. Again, VirtualBox networking is screwed, it breaks the normal networking layering somehow. It is possible that it is tapped earlier than winpcap (which Wireshark uses to capture packets), so those packets don't reach Wireshark's tap. Generally in such cases you put *all* your test systems into virtual environments, make dedicated private networks between them and then it doesn't matter much how the networking in the virtualization system behaves.

Comment: The problem is, my "test system" is an embedded system that should boot from the tftp server, so no way to virtualize that. But still, somehow it should be possible to reach a tftp server inside a VM or not? :/

Comment: It should be possible. Try using "host-only" network and bridge it by OS means with the physical NIC rather than using built-in Virtualbox "bridge". That way you should definitely observe packets when capturing on "host-only" NIC counterpart in the host.

Comment: According to the table under 6.2 here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html "host-only" is not applicable if I need to access the VM from outside my host. So I should probably use NAT and then forward the ports for TFTP and SSH? But that would mean that my VM doesn't have a dedicated IP address?

Comment: Technically all the VM communication is "host-only" by the virtual nature of the VM. It is host what makes it possible to communicate with the external world, and there are different ways to do that. Generally, you can do that by bridging (L2) or routing (L3) that host part of host-to-VM connection *on the host*. The thing that VirtualBox calls "bridging" is actually VirtualBox's quirky "third mode" where it penetrates into the host networking stack to make it appear as if it is bridged without the need to manually instantiate the proper OS-level bridge.

Comment: It is not the first time I see the confusion caused by this "simplification" that VirtualBox appears to make, and a confusion of what is "host-only" and what does that really mean. Consider network layering (e. g. OSI model); VM does not exist on the L1, but on L2 and further it is the system in the full right. On L2 host has two NICs, one "physical" with external jack, other "virtual" whose other end is connected to the VM's NIC. That second NIC *is* the host only NIC and without special setup it is really host-only. But once you bridge it, magic happens.